# YAML Issue in Ansible 2.3.0

Tags: ansible, yaml

I got this playbook to run on a VM running Ansible 2.3.1, with no errors, however, I am running into problems with the very first character in other versions 2.3.0 and older and I am NOT seeing where I am going wrong.

The format exactly follows the examples given in the documentation for cl-license, and this is pretty vanilla in that there is no logic or conditional statements or anything to this YAML.

```
---
- hosts: accton_as6712_32x
  tasks:
    - name: install_license_for_6712
      cl_license:
        src: "http://10.43.255.182/cumulus/license-4x5712-4x6712.txt"

- hosts: accton_as4610_54
  tasks:
    - name: install_license_for_4610
      cl_license:
        src: "http://10.43.255.182/cumulus/license-2x4600.txt"

- hosts: mlnx_x86_MSN2410B
  tasks:
    - name: install_license_for_2410
      cl_license:
        src: "http://10.43.255.182/cumulus/license-2x2410.txt"

- hosts: mlnx_x86_MSN2700
  tasks:
    - name: install_license_for_2700
      cl_license:
        src: "http://10.43.255.182/cumulus/license-mellanox-demo-2700.txt"
```

This is the error I get from Jenkins/Ansible:

```
The offending line appears to be:
---
- hosts: accton_as6712_32x
  ^ here
```

And if I use YAML Lint, I get this error:

```
(<unknown>): did not find expected '-' indicator while parsing a block collection at line 2 column 1
```

I am fairly new to Ansible and would love if somebody could point out where I am going wrong?

Comment: Check for broken indentation. The error says that it can't parse the first list, because there may be some broken indentation or unexpected characters (may be at the very end of the file), but error pointer is set to the beginning of broken element.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not saying the `cl-license` module is the wrong way but have you considered using [ZTP](https://docs.cumulusnetworks.com/display/DOCS/Zero+Touch+Provisioning+-+ZTP) to install licenses on your Cumulus switches?

By the way, the indentation looks correct but make sure you have actual spaces and not tab characters in your file. Also, check for any odd trailing spaces.